# Update Button Title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a simple button which is initially labelled with the emoji , and all that I'm trying to do is to remove the emoji once the button is clicked.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flipCard(withEmoji: "", on: sender)
    }

    func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button:UIButton){
        if button.currentTitle == emoji {
            button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            print("Removed emoji")
        }
    }

}
```

As I step through the code, the statement `button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)` gets executed, however the emoji does not disappear although it does appear faded, after the button is clicked.

**Edit:** The title does get updated, but it takes a few (8-10) seconds to do so. Replacing the emoji with another emoji is almost instantaneous though! What could be causing this and how do I fix this?

PS: I'm following along the CS193P lecture (Lecture 1) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71pyOB4TPRE&t=2776s).

Comment: Have you set different titles for different states or just the "normal" state?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `button.title(for: .normal)` instead of `button.currentTitle`.

Answer (score 0):

If the button appears faded, it might be disabled. If you set the title for the disabled state and execute `button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)`, nothing will happen to the title for `UIControl.State.disabled`.

Check if `button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.disabled)` does the trick.

Comment: This is only true if different titles have been set for different states. If a title has only been set for the "normal" state, that title is used for all states.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear enough. The button appears faded after it is clicked. It looks like the desired action does take place, but the emoji disappears from the UI after about 10 seconds, not instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace your function like below function that i have added for you.

```
func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button:UIButton){

        if button.currentTitle == emoji {

            button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            button.setTitle("", for: .selected)
            button.setTitle("", for: .disabled)

            print("Removed emoji")
        }

    }
```

Hope this way may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It did not help unfortunately. I tried changing the button a Custom button as well but the updates still seem to lag by a click i.e. the background change and title update is not reflected until the second click, and then continues to lag by a click.